# Moodle: quiz with limited seats

Tags: moodle

I'm looking for this feature for moodle:

- Create a quiz
- Set N avaiable seats
- When the last seat is taken, close the quiz.

I have been looking for a plugin with such a feature but I didn't have luck, so I guess I have to implement this function by myself but I'm a little bit lost.

Could someone with some moodle programming experience put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best workaround I could find, from Moodle Forum

How about using Conditional activities, Activity completion and the Choice module?

1. Ensure you have conditional activities and completion tracking enabled in your site/course
2. Make a choice with just one choice "Sign up for the Quiz" Restrict the number of people allowed to make the choice to two.
3. Set the activity completion to "when conditions are met" and the condition is "students must make a choice"
4. Go to your quiz and set the Restrict access condition to - quiz will become available once Choice is marked complete..
5. The first two people to go to the Choice module and click the "Sign up for the "Quiz" button will get it marked complete and that will open up the Quiz. Any third or later person going to the Choice will not be able to sign up because only two places were allowed. Because they cannot complete the activity, the quiz will not become visible to them and they can't do it.

**https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=257726**

Answer (score 0):

There is not a plugin with your specific needs, but the solution to your problem is simple:

- create a course with max enrolled user set.
- create a quiz attached to that course.

Self enrolment has a max enrolled users administration option. :-)

Comment: I thought about this, but it will be a mess, imagine if I have a course with hundreds of students and hundreds of quiz, it won't be possible to solve the problem in the way you suggested me :)